# extended View class object not rendered (XML ) in Android Studio or on Phone

Tags: android

I extended View like so:

```
public class ZoomView extends View {}
```

and created a place for the ZoomView in the layout .XML like so:

```
<sic.example.guestbookapp.ZoomView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bodyshape"
    android:id="@+id/BodyPicture" />
```

which is SO COOL that I can extend widgets and then cast

```
(ZoomView) findViewById(R.id.BodyPicture);
```

Problem is that the drawable image is not rendered in Studio or on the phone.

UPDATE here's the answer:
the fix is to extend ImageView rather than View, than all is fine.

```
public class ZoomView extends ImageView {}
```

(answering my own question)

Answer (score 0):

the fix is to extend ImageView rather than View, than all is fine.

```
public class ZoomView extends ImageView {}
```

(answering my own question)